# Sitefinity add fields through backend code

Tags: sitefinity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCmog.png)

I have a project where I need to add the customized field use code dynamically , now siteifinity provides user to add in the backend pages as the picture shows.  Is any there way to add through code?  Now I can add more field column into the table use fluent API, but the newly added field is not shown in the backend page.  how to make the newly added field to show in the backend module ?

Comment: Can you show the code you used to add a new field and where you put it?

Comment: currently , I add the field to the content type in the backend page UI , simply click to added and fields will be logged into database , now i want to control the workflow using code , where I can add more field to content type dynamically .